# how to stop activity recreation on screen orientation?

Tags: android

How can I stop the restarting or recalling of on `create()` on screen orientation, I want to stop the recreation of activity on screen orientation. Please tell me any better solution it is really creating a problem. like in my program I am selecting some pictures but on screen orientation, the image goes off so that's why I want to stop the recreation of activity on screen orientation.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainwindow);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"a", 1).show();
    
    bitmap = (Bitmap)getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"a1", 1).show();
    
    if (savedInstanceState != null) 
    {
        bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mImageCaptureUri.getPath());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"preview have value", 1).show();
        preview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        From_Folder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        From_Camera.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        preview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    
    
    }
```

Answer (score 32):

Up to `API 13` there was a new value to the `configChanges` attribute, **`screenSize`**

So if you're using large screens make sure to add screenSize in your configChanges attribute:

```
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

Comment: it's enough only two parameters android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"

Comment: `screenLayout` is also needed to prevent layout changes

Answer (score 11):

This is happening because when screen orientation rotates the Activity gets re-started. In this case you can add `configChanges` attribute in your tag in the AndroidManifest file to stop the re-creation of the Activity.

```
<activity android:name=".Activity_name"
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
```

By, this also it won't stop though the orientation changes.

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
            setContentView(R.layout.login_landscape);
        }
        else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            setContentView(R.layout.login);         
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this was a great solution for maintaining dialogs on orientation change

Comment: in API 13 must incluse also the `screenSize` value to manifest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11630530/how-to-handle-screen-orientation-changes-when-there-is-an-asyntask-running-with

Answer (score 5):

In your AndroidManifest.xml file, in the activity add

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

Example as below:

```
 <activity android:name=".YourActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
```

Comment: yes it is working after adding these lines to my manifestandroid:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
it is working 100%

Answer (score 3):

Not the best, but maybe the easiest solution is to add

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

to youractivity in your manifest so it looks like

```
<activity android:name="com.your.activity"
      android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
```

Comment: This is an anti-pattern and must be discouraged. You HAVE to manage the scenario where activity is recreated, since it happens not only when the device is rotated, but when the SO kills activity to release memory. Manage your layout configuration changes and activity recreation using Loaders or ViewModel and Lifecycle components.

Answer (score 2):

There are a more full list of parameters for prevent activity recreations (in Manifest.xml):

```
<activity 
    android:name = ".MyActivity" 
    android:configChanges = "orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways for this:

Either you can set android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" in Manifest file to avoid recreation of activity.

Or
Make the changes you want to apply on changing the orientation inside the overrided method

@Override

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

            // Perform the actions

    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

}
```

Answer (score -3):

Add

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

or

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

to your layout in `mainwindow.xml`.

Example:::

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

No need to add anything in Activity class.

Hope this may help you