# configChanges="orientation" doesn't trigger on Galaxy Nexus

Tags: android, orientation, galaxy-nexus

Hello I have a strange bug, when I want to trigger the orientation change on the Galaxy Nexus(4.0.4), it simply doesn't jump into the `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration)` function.
On the HTC Desire(4.0.4) it works without any issues with the same code. And even on an emulator with 720p it works. I tried to update to Android 4.1, but I still have the same problem.

Does anyone have the same problems or any solutions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see both devices running Android 4.x, but try adding `screenSize` value as described in my earlier answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11631017/716075).

Answer (score 0):

In the manifest, int the `<activity>` tag, add `android:configChanges="orientation"`. This tells the system that your activity will handle orientation changes by itself, hence the onConfigurationChanged() will be triggered.

Comment: I already added this line in the manifest, sorry I should say it in my post

Answer (score 0):

`screenSize` flag on Android 4.X needed.
Try another android compiler builder.

Answer (score 0):

If you have called `setRequestedOrientation(..)` in the activity before, the `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration)` will not be triggered by the system auto-detect of rotation.