# camera crash unexpectedly in galaxy nexus

Tags: android, camera

I have a strange issue in my camera app when tested with galaxy nexus..It simply crash when try to start the camera activity..But it works fine with almost all other devices..
These are my functions.....

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     try {
        camera = Camera.open();
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        if (Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) >= 8)
            setDisplayOrientation(camera, 90);
        else
            parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");
        parameters.setPictureFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);



    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 


}
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
  int height) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 if(previewing){
  camera.stopPreview();
  previewing = false;
 }

 if (camera != null){
  try {


   camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
   camera.startPreview();
   previewing = true;
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

Can anyone help 
me ?

Comment: Put the Exception/Crash logcat too.

Comment: @AdilSoomro sorry..unfortunately i dont have it now..i dont have the nexus phone also..

Comment: probably becoz you are starting & stopping camera in surfaceChanged. Its better to startPreview in onResume() and stopPreview in onPause().Its working for my application over galaxy nexus.

Comment: One more thing is that, i am adding "targetSDKVersion=15" in my manifest file..Also there is a statement "android:configChanges" in my activity declaration in manifest as "android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout""..Is there any issue here ?

Comment: No this won't effect. For ScreenLayout, I'm not sure but for other options(keyboardHidden|orientation) as I have used these in my manifest too...

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11630530/how-to-handle-screen-orientation-changes-when-there-is-an-asyntask-running-with/11631017#11631017

Comment: @bugfinder: well! in that scene I would suggest you to download a galaxy nexus emulator and debug the app. :)

Comment: sorry to be ignoramus, how to download galaxy nexus emulator ?

Comment: i tried with nexus like emulator..but no crashes..

Comment: @bugfinder I have Galaxy Nexus phone. If you'll create project, that I could quickly import to Eclipse, I can try to reproduce the issue and debug it.

Comment: @vArDo pls get me your email id ?

Comment: @vArDo i can mail u the project..

Comment: @bugfinder kjkjkjkj123123@gmail.com

Comment: @hacker: hi, I'm facing issues regarding preview orientation and crash in ICS.I would be really grateful if you can email me your demo application at `mehuljoisar@gmail.com`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

finally i got the answer..Nexus has both front and back end cameras.So the problem was the code which used to open the camera(need to set the camera id for the front end camera) and also we need to set the appropriate preview size..Here is the modified code..

```
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
  int height) {



    List<Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    Size optimalSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(sizes, width, height);
    parameters.setPreviewSize(optimalSize.width, optimalSize.height);

    camera.setParameters(parameters);
    camera.startPreview();
     startPreview();

}


   @Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {


     try {

         if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
              Camera.CameraInfo info=new Camera.CameraInfo();

              for (int i=0; i < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); i++) {
                Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);

                if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                  camera=Camera.open(i);
                  defaultCameraId = i;
                }
              }
            }

            if (camera == null) {
              camera=Camera.open();
            }




            try {
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
            android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
                    new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
            android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(defaultCameraId, info);
            int rotation = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                    .getRotation();
            if (Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) >= 8)
            {

                 int degrees = 0;
                 switch (rotation) {
                     case Surface.ROTATION_0: 
                         degrees = 0; break;
                     case Surface.ROTATION_90: 
                         degrees = 90; break;
                     case Surface.ROTATION_180: 
                         degrees = 180; break;
                     case Surface.ROTATION_270: 
                         degrees = 270; break;
                 }
                 int result;
                 if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                     result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
                     result = (360 - result) % 360;  
                 } else {  // back-facing
                     result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
                 }
                 camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);

            }
            else
            {
                parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");
            }


            camera.setParameters(parameters);



    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 


}


    private Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
                final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
                double targetRatio = (double) w / h;
                if (sizes == null) return null;

                Size optimalSize = null;
                double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

                int targetHeight = h;


                for (Size size : sizes) {
                    double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
                    if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
                    if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                        optimalSize = size;
                        minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                    }
                }


                if (optimalSize == null) {
                    minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
                    for (Size size : sizes) {
                        if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                            optimalSize = size;
                            minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return optimalSize;
            }
```