# onConfigurationChanged not getting called on rotation

Tags: android, onconfigurationchanged

my problem is onConfigurationChanged is not getting called.

Code is as follows:

```
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    Log.i("onconfig", "#### CALLED!"); 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        LinearLayout listContainer = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.list_container);

        if(newConfig.orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
            listContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        }
        else{
            listContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        }
//      end if else
        }
// end of on configuration changed
```

In the manifest I have:

```
<activity
        android:name=".FirstListActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_fruits_list"
            android:configChanges="orientation">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: Are you missing the @Override annotation before `public void onConfigurationChanged`

Comment: @forgivegod `@Override` doesn't effect if it works or not. it's just a reminder and is good practice.

Comment: @Override doesn't do anything other than help you avoid typos. From the code you've posted I think it should work, you'll probably have to post more complete code to get a decent answer (and a proper minimal example rather than a huge dump). Sorry!

Comment: You probably need to add screenSize to `android:configChagnes="orientation|screenSize"`, if you are targeting API level 13 and higher. Here is the source: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange

Comment: Thanks everyone. Targeting API 10. Haven't solved it yet.

Comment: I'm using an application class would this make a difference as to how this is managed?

Answer (score 2):

Add `screenSize` value as well in `android:configChanges` attribute tag. for more read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11630530/how-to-handle-screen-orientation-changes-when-there-is-an-asyntask-running-with/11631017#11631017)

Answer (score 0):

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6109206/1182515

Do you use this method in your onCreate?

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

When using that you will not receive orientation changes.

Try the solutions given in the linked post.