# Can't save fragment state in Android while configuration is changed

Tags: android, android-fragments, parcelable, android-savedstate

This type of question is asked many times in SO, I have tried all of them, but couldn't achieve what I actually want. In my app I have `Fragment`, inside that fragment I have a `recycler` view. `recyclerview` would be manipulated by the data which I have got from API.

What I want that when rotation is changed, the app doesn't call the API again. To achieve this I know I have to put the data in `onSaveInstanceState`, If I want to save a complex object then the class must be implements `Parcelable`. I have done everything that is recommended, but couldn't achieve what I want.

I am sharing my code here, I have created a simplified example.

Code for **SimpleFragment.java**

```
public class SimpleFragment extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ArrayList<TestModel> testModelList = new ArrayList<TestModel>() ;
    SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_fragment, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity());

        recyclerView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);


        if(savedInstanceState != null){
            //if this fragment starts after a rotation or configuration change, load the existing model from a parcelable
            testModelList = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("key");
            // I have done necessary debug , after rotation , it comes here ,
            // but suddenly savedInstanceState becomes null and getTestModelList() get called


        }else {
            //if this fragment starts for the first time, load the list of model
           getTestModelList();
        }

        simpleAdapter.setModel(testModelList);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putParcelableArrayList("key",testModelList);
    }

    public void getTestModelList(){
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
            testModelList.add(new TestModel(i,"test"+i));
        }
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Called",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

layout file for SimpleFragment: **simple_fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is code for my data model **TestModel.java**

```
public class TestModel implements Parcelable {

    String text;

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public TestModel(int number, String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }


    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(this.text);
    }

    protected TestModel(Parcel in) {
        this.text = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<TestModel> CREATOR
            = new Parcelable.Creator<TestModel>() {
        public TestModel createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new TestModel(in);
        }

        public TestModel[] newArray(int size) {
            return new TestModel[size];
        }
    };
}
```

My adapter class: **SimpleAdapter.java**

```
public class SimpleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<TestModel> testModels;

    public SimpleAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void setModel(ArrayList<TestModel> model){
        this.testModels = model;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_row, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.list_item.setText(testModels.get(position).getText());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return testModels.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView list_item;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            list_item = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item);
        }
    }
}
```

Code for single row layout for adapter **single_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/list_item"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

These are what I have done, and if change the orientation  `getTestModelList()` method in my SimpleFragment is called again, which I want to avoid; in real app scenario this method will do some API call. I want to save the state of `ArrayList<TestModel> testModelList`.

Answer (score 2):

you need to save state of activity and check it before configuration

follow this code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{


    private HomeFragment homeFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();


           if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            homeFragment = new HomeFragment();


            ((fm.beginTransaction()).replace(R.id.mainframe, homeFragment)).commit();
        }
}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can save Fragment instance like this in Fragment `onCreate` method for orientation change to save instance :

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         // Set Instance true
        this.setRetainInstance(true);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks , Tried it , but didn't work ,  getTestModelList() function called when orientation is changed .

Comment: No need to call `getTestModelList()` method...when your instance is set to `true` it will maintain your state when your orientation is changed

`RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
         getTestModelList();
        simpleAdapter.setModel(testModelList);` do like this

Comment: I didn't call it explicitly , this method get called automatically

Comment: have your tried the following code i mentioned in the comment?

Comment: set like this in your fragment's activity in manifest `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`

Comment: yes , I have tried  , and your last comment won't allow me to use separate layout for landscape

Comment: You can keep both layouts

Comment: I have tested this , if I put  android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" , then separate layout won't load .

Answer (score 1):

Android recreates your activity whenever the orientation changes. The reason behind this is you may need to change your layout but you can still achieve that with `onConfigurationChanged()` of the `Activity` or the `Fragment` I suggest you to add

`android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"`

in your manifest file (refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814551/how-to-stop-activity-recreation-on-screen-orientation) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097909/android-orientation-change-calls-oncreate)). This will stop recreation of Activity on Confifuration changes.

Comment: Thanks , I knew this , but what if I want to use  separate layout for landscape ? In this method the separate layout won't load .

Comment: Like I said you can still achieve that with `onConfigurationChanged()` callback.